# running openstack under opensuse 13.1?

Tags: openstack, opensuse

How do I run openstack under an opensuse fresh installation version 13.1?

I have installed opensuse 13.1, I am a novice and I would to create my own cloud on this system, with virtual machine that works at client node. But I am not able to run the openstack graphical interface.

Is it possible to launch the interface before starting all requirements configuration?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to install openstack is using Devstack - http://devstack.org/

The instructions there are for Ubuntu and Fedora, but you should be able to adapt the script to run on OpenSuse

Answer (score 0):

You can follow official documentation which has SUSE Linux Openstack Install instructions http://docs.openstack.org/havana/install-guide/install/zypper/content/

Hope it helps.